# Regex for matching a list of ports in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I wrote a pattern to match a list of ports in the CSV format, e.g., `80, 8080,53,  4444` with the support for multiple whitespaces (which will be deleted in a following process).

This is the pattern: `^\d{1,5}(\s*,\s*\d{1,5})*$`

However, I'd like to accept port ranges (e.g., `22-25`), as well. To provide further examples, the following strings should be all accepted:

```
80 , 22-25,8080  ,   4444-5555
80
80-81
5555-6000,1111-2222  ,  80
```

Comment: Is `80` between this range? `22-25`

Comment: No, 80 is after 25... Ports follow numeric order.

Comment: Something like [`^\d{1,5}(?:-\d{1,5})?(\s*,\s*\d{1,5}(?:-\d{1,5})?)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/jT8oD9/1)?

Comment: Yes, it works well, thank you. Please post as answer so that I can vote that! ;)